# makefile リンク順序を揃えても未定義の参照というエラーになる原因が知りたい

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw

#### 質問内容

コンパイルを行うと以下のエラーが起きますが原因がわかりません。
`undefined reference to glfwInit`未定義の参照とあとりますが何が原因なのでしょうか？
インクルードファイル、リンク、ともに行っています。

#### 状況

FrameWork.aはglew,glfw,openglを使っています

#### 調べたこと

利用ライブラリはopengl,glfw,glew,freetypeです。

１，参考サイトの順序サイトより`AがBに依存する場合AはBよりも前に来ないと行かない`を参考に依存する順番に記述しましたが以下のエラーがでます。

２，様々な順序でリンクして実行
３，ファイル名を確認、提示画像参照
４，glew32,glew32s共に実験

#### 入手先

glew: https://glew.sourceforge.net/
glfw: https://www.glfw.org/

#### 参考サイト

順序：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819869/linker-error-on-glfw-on-linux-x11
defineを配置：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18475234/undefined-references-to-imp-glew-functions-with-mingw-gcc

##### 環境

OS: ubuntu

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

##### エラー(長いため一部省略)

```
$ make
g++ obj/Main.o -o program  -L../bin  -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/glew32s.lib ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -lGL -ldl -lm -lGLU -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0xd): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0xf): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'
//x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x363): undefined reference to `__imp_glGetString'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x2d): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetCurrentDC'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x1c): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x30): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetProcAddress'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glew32s.lib(tmp/glew_static/Release/x64/glew.obj):(.text$mn+0x5c): undefined reference to `__imp_wglGetCurrentDC'
j):(.text$mn+0x105): undefined reference to `__imp_CloseClipboard'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x30): undefined reference to `__imp_SetCursor'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x3d): undefined reference to `__imp_LoadCursorW'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x4c): undefined reference to `__imp_SetCursor'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x5a): undefined reference to `__imp_SetCursor'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x13): undefined reference to `__imp_GetActiveWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x2e): undefined reference to `__imp_ClientToScreen'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x3c): undefined reference to `__imp_SetCursorPos'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x37): undefined reference to `__imp_RegisterRawInputDevices'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x71): undefined reference to `__imp_RegisterRawInputDevices'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/wi
```

###### makefile

```
PRG         :=program
OBJ_DIR     :=obj
SRC_DIR     :=src
DEP_DIR     :=obj
DEP         :=$(wildcard $(DEP_DIR)/*.d)
SRC         :=$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ         :=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC))))


$(PRG): $(OBJ) 
#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin ~/Library/lib/glew32s.lib ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11
#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/glew32s.lib ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11
#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/glew32s.lib -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11

#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/glew32.lib -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11
#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  ~/Library/lib/glew32.lib ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11
#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/glew32.lib ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11

#   $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/glew32s.lib ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L../bin  -lFrameWork ~/Library/lib/glew32s.lib ~/Library/lib/glfw3.lib ~/Library/lib/freetype.lib -ldl -lm -lGL -lGLU -lX11


$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c -MMD -MP $< -o $@ -I ~/prg/2DFrameWork/src -I ~/Library -I ~/Library/freetype 
-include $(DEP)

clean:
    rm -f ./$(OBJ_DIR)/*.o *.out ./$(OBJ_DIR)/*.d $(PRG)
```

##### ソースコード

```cpp
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <FrameWork.hpp>
#include "glfw/glfw3.h"

int main()
{

    if (glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE)
    {
        assert(0 && "glfw");
    }

    FrameWork::Window::windowContext = std::make_shared<FrameWork::Window>(glm::ivec2(800, 800), "Hello World");
    FrameWork::Window::windowContext->setCurrentContext();

    // OpenGL Verison 4.5 Core Profile
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 5);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    {
        assert(0 && "glew");
    }
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);              
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);                            
    glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);                            
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);  
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);                                 
    glEnable(GL_SAMPLE_ALPHA_TO_COVERAGE);              
    glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);                           


    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    //glCullFace(GL_FRONT);



    FrameWork::Sprite::Init();


    std::shared_ptr<FrameWork::Camera> camera = std::make_shared<FrameWork::Camera>(FrameWork::Window::windowContext);
    
    camera->shader = std::make_shared<FrameWork::Shader>();
    //camera->shader->Load("asset/shader/FrameBuffer_depth.vert", "asset/shader/FrameBuffer_depth.frag");
    camera->shader->Load("asset/shader/FrameBuffer.vert", "asset/shader/FrameBuffer.frag");
    camera->shader->setVertexAttribute(camera->frameBuffer->quadVAO, camera->frameBuffer->quadVBO, "vertexPosition", 4, sizeof(FrameWork::VertexAttribute_Sprite), 0);
    camera->shader->setVertexAttribute(camera->frameBuffer->quadVAO, camera->frameBuffer->quadVBO, "vertexUV", 4, sizeof(FrameWork::VertexAttribute_Sprite), 3 * sizeof(float));
    
    camera->setPosition(glm::vec3(0, 0, 10));
    camera->setLook(glm::vec3(0, 0, -1));


    while (*FrameWork::Window::windowContext)
    {   

        
        camera->frameBuffer->OffScreenRender_Enable();


        camera->frameBuffer->OffScreenRender_Disable();

        
        camera->shader->setEnable();
        
        camera->frameBuffer->ScreenRender_Enable();
        camera->shader->setUniformSampler2D("uImage", 0, camera->frameBuffer->texture);
        camera->frameBuffer->ScreenRender();
        camera->frameBuffer->ScreenRender_Disable();
        camera->shader->setDisable();
        
        
        FrameWork::Window::windowContext->SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: リンク時に`glfwInit()`が含まれているライブラリを指定していないように見えますが、`-lglfw3`等は指定していますか？[`pkg-config`が使える環境ならそれを使う](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_link_pkgconfig)のが良さそう。

Comment: 本番環境ではこういった形にしていますがどちらも同じエラーが出ます。`$(CXX) $^ -o $@  -L~/Library/lib/glfw3 -L~/Library/lib/glew32s -L~/Library/lib/freetype -ldl -lX11 -L./bin/FrameWork.a -lGL -lGLU -ldl -lGLESv2 -pthread `

Comment: `-l`で指定しているライブラリの中に`glfwInit()`は含まれていますか？調べてないけど、名前から推測して`libglfw3.a`の中に含まれているだと思うんだけど。

Comment: なるほど質問ですが自分はglfw3.libを使っているのですがubuntuなのでビルドするなしりしてlibglfw3.aを取得しないといけないのでしょうか？

Comment: 親切にも[GLFWのドキュメントページ](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html#build_link_pkgconfig)からリンクされている[Beginner's Guide to Linkers](https://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#staticlibs)に記載されている通り、Unix系のリンカーは`-lglfw3`と指定すると静的ライブラリの場合は`libglfw3.a`を探しに行きます。この命名規約に合わせるか、`-l`を使わずに`glfw3.lib`のフルパス名を直に指定してください。

Comment: はい。行いましたが質問文ようなエラーが起きます。順序を確認しましたが原因がわかりません。

Comment: OSは何をお使いなのでしょうか？ 「OS: ubuntu」と明記されているものの、Makefile内には「glew32s.lib」とWindows用のバイナリを参照されています。*.libの入手元を明記してください。

Comment: OSはubuntuです。windowのlibファイルを使っているのですがこれが問題でしょうか？上のコメントでは-lを使わずにxxx.liibとフルパスを入力してくださいとのことでしたので

Comment: `.lib`でまさか……とは思ったけど、そっからか……先は長そうですね。

Comment: 問題ない場合もありますが基本的にはだめなのでしょうか？

Comment: 過去の関連質問: [g++ glfwがリンクできない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/85592)

Comment: ヘッダファイルなどは OS 問わず共通ですが、バイナリファイルは OS 間で基本的に互換性はありません。[ダウンロードページ](https://www.glfw.org/download.html) の説明もよく読みましょう。(なぜわざわざ OS ごとにファイルが分かれているのかを考えるべき)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージより

> ```
> /usr/bin/ld: /home/linux/Library/lib/glfw3.lib(glfw.dir/Release/win32_window.obj):(.text$mn+0x30): undefined reference to `__imp_SetCursor'
> ```

これは、[Windows APIの`SetCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor)を呼び出すために`User32.lib`に含まれている`__imp_SetCursor`が必要なことを指摘しています。
もちろん実行時には`User32.dll`に含まれる`SetCursor`が必要です。

Linux上でWindowsバイナリをリンクしても何の意味もありませんので、考えを改めることをお勧めします。

Comment: 拡張子まで含まれば.libを使えますが通常は「原因：linux専用に.aファイルを生成する」でした。